# PHP Traits: How to circumvenient constructors or force them to be called?

Tags: php, inheritance, constructor, traits

Have a look at the following trait:

```
trait PrimaryModelRest {

    use RestController;

    protected $primaryModel;

    public function __construct() {
        $mc = $this->getPrimaryModelClass();

        try {
            $this->primaryModel = new $mc();
            if(!($this->primaryModel instanceof Model)) {
                throw new ClassNotFoundException("Primary Model fatal exception: The given Class is not an instance of Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model");
            }
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new WrongImplementationException("Primary Model Exception: Class not found.");
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return string: Classname of the primary model.
     */
    public abstract function getPrimaryModelClass();

    // various functions here

}
```

As you can see the trait makes sure that the using class holds a certain model instance and it implements certain methods. This works ***as long as the implementing class does not override the constructor***.

So here is my question: I want to make sure that either the constructor is called or a better solution, such that I can instantiate this model on initialization.

Please make in answer which respects **Multiple inheritance** as well es **Multi-Level inheritance**.

Comment: `final public function __construct()` to prevent the implementing class from overriding the constructor?

Comment: Nice but what if the implementing class should have an constructor anyway and just make sure that the trait constructor is called, too?

Comment: Then you have to "trust" that the implementing class calls the trait constructor; you can't enforce it in code if you allow the implementing class to have its own constructor

Comment: final means this will not be overridable (class that uses trait will not be able to override this). On other note: traits should not contain constructors, if you have a generic constructor put it in abstract class, and extend that, that way you will have control of when you override it or extend it

Comment: Ok thanks. Is there something like a magic "onCreation" method in PHP?

Comment: `Is there something like a magic "onCreation" method in PHP?` Yes there is.... it's called `__construct()` And any magical method can be overridden unless you finalise it

Comment: Why don't you just instantiate the property `primaryModel` in a getter? `public function getPrimaryModel() { if ($this->primaryModel === null) { ...} return $this->primaryModel; } `

Comment: What you could try doing is allowing a customised closure to be passed to your finalised contructor, that you can then call if it's defined, and that can be used as an alternative to a child constructor

Comment: @DarkBee Is there also a solution for the case that a subclass tries to access the property directly?

Comment: @Baker Nice workaround in some cases but not easy to read in the subclasses and it even more nasty to scale about multiple inheritance levels.

Comment: Make the property private?

Comment: Your bounty description makes no sense, because **PHP does not have multiple inheritance**, except in the extremely limited sense provided by interfaces. In particular, **traits are not an inheritance mechanism**; they are "horizontal reuse" - reuse of code between *unrelated* classes. A common description is "machine-assisted copy-and-paste". Using them to assist with complex multi-level contracts is simply not what they were designed for.

Comment: @IMSoP So traits are primarily a way for avoiding duplicate code. But traits actually **are allowed to define member variables and also initialize those**. Why is this possible if they are for code duplication only?

If you have a solution avoiding traits which solves this problem it is also fine! If the answer is, that this is impossible in PHP thats also o.k. but I really want a good reasoning then.

Comment: @Blackbam Why is defining and initializing member variables different from any other code you might want to copy-and-paste?

Comment: @IMSoP The difference is that the only thing I miss is that I can initialize those member variables properly. I am searching for a way to make sure that the member variables are initialized as soon as the object is instantiated, with or without constructor.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you are trying to make the trait do a job it is not designed for.

Traits are not a form of multiple inheritance, but rather "horizontal reuse" - they're often described as "compiler-assisted copy-and-paste". As such, the job of a trait is to *provide some code*, so that you don't have to copy it into the class manually. The only relationship it has is with the class where the `use` statement occurs, where the code is "pasted". To aid in this role, it can make some basic requirements *of that target class*, but after that, **the trait takes no part in inheritance**.

In your example, you are concerned that a sub-class might try to access `$primaryModel` without running the constructor code which initialises it, and you are trying to use the trait to enforce that; but this is not actually the trait's responsibility.

The following definitions of class `Sub` are completely equivalent:

```
trait Test {
    public function foo() {
        echo 'Hello, World!';
    }
}
class ParentWithTrait {
    use Test;
}
class Sub inherits ParentWithTrait {
}
```

vs:

```
class ParentWithMethodDefinition {
    public function foo() {
        echo 'Hello, World!';
    }
}
class Sub inherits ParentWithMethodDefinition {
}
```

In either case, class `Sub` could have its own definition of `foo()`, and by-pass the logic you'd written in the parent class.

The only contract that can prevent that is the `final` keyword, which in your case would mean marking your constructor as `final`. You can then provide an extension point that *can* be overridden for sub-classes to add their own initialisation:

```
class Base {
    final public function __construct() {
         important_things(); // Always run this!
         $this->onConstruct(); // Extension point
    }
    protected function onConstruct() {
         // empty default definition
    }
}
class Sub {
    protected function onConstruct() {
         stuff_for_sub(); // Runs after mandatory important_things()
    }
}
```

A trait can also mark its constructor as final, but *this is part of the code being pasted*, not a requirement on the class using the trait. You could actually use a trait with a constructor, but then write a new constructor as well, and it would mask the trait's version completely:

```
trait Test {
    final public function __construct() {
        echo "Trait Constructor";
    }
}
class Noisy {
    use Test;
}
class Silent {
    use Test;
    public function __construct() {
        // Nothing
    }
}
```

As far as the trait is concerned, this is like buying a bottle of beer and pouring it down the sink: you asked for its code and didn't use it, but that's your problem.

Crucially, though, you can also *alias* the methods of the trait, creating a new method with the same code but a different name and/or a different visibility. This means you can mix in code from traits which declare constructors, and use that code in a more complex constructor, or somewhere else in the class altogether.

The target class might also use the "final + hook" pattern:

```
trait TestOne {
    final public function __construct() {
        echo "Trait TestOne Constructor\n";
    }
}
trait TestTwo {
    final public function __construct() {
        echo "Trait TestTwo Constructor\n";
    }
}
class Mixed {
    final public function __construct() {
        echo "Beginning\n";
        $this->testOneConstructor();
        echo "Middle\n";
        $this->testTwoConstructor();
        echo "After Traits\n";
        $this->onConstruct();
        echo "After Sub-Class Hook\n";
    }
    use TestOne { __construct as private testOneConstructor; }
    use TestTwo { __construct as private testTwoConstructor; }

    protected function onConstruct() {
        echo "Default hook\n";
    }
}
class ChildOfMixed extends Mixed {
    protected function onConstruct() {
        echo "Child hook\n";
    }
}
```

The trait hasn't *forced* the `Mixed` class to implement this pattern, but it has *enabled* it, in keeping with its purpose of facilitating code reuse.

Interestingly, the below code *doesn't* work, because the `as` keyword *adds* an alias, rather than renaming the normal method, so this ends up trying to override the `final` constructor from `Mixed`:

```
class ChildOfMixed extends Mixed {
    use TestTwo { __construct as private testTwoConstructor; }

    protected function onConstruct() {
        $this->testTwoConstructor();
        echo "Child hook\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitly some interesting points I will have some experiments with this.

Answer (score 3):

Use a base class, this will let you handle the trait as a parent.

```
<?php

trait StorageTrait
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo "Storage Trait";
    }
}

class StorageAttempt
{
    use StorageTrait;

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo " - Storage Attempt";
    }
}


abstract class StorageBase
{
    use StorageTrait;
}

class MyStorage extends StorageBase
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo ' - My Storage';
    }
}


new StorageAttempt(); // won't work - will trigger error
new MyStorage(); // will display "Storage Trait - My Storage"
```

Also if you are using traits you can also work with properties and getters & setters.

Example: A Storage trait involves that a `Storage Engine` will be used. You can add the storageEngine property and its getters and setters. (with or without Type Hinting)

```
interface StorageEngineInterface{}

trait StorageTrait
{
    /**
     * @var StorageEngineInterface
     */
    protected $storageEngine;

    /**
     * @return StorageEngineInterface
     */
    public function getStorageEngine(): StorageEngineInterface
    {
        return $this->storageEngine;
    }

    /**
     * @param StorageEngineInterface $storageEngine
     */
    public function setStorageEngine(StorageEngineInterface $storageEngine)
    {
        $this->storageEngine = $storageEngine;
        return $this;
    }
}
```

> Note: this is just an explanation so you can better understand how `Traits` work

**UPDATE**

To avoid conflict you can use aliases for trait methods. This way you can use both constructors (from trait and from extended class) you can do the following

```
class DifferentStorage
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo ' diff ';
    }
}

class MyDifferentStorage extends DifferentStorage
{
    use StorageTrait {
        StorageTrait::__construct as otherConstructor;
    }

    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        self::otherConstructor();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but as soon as Storage attempt extends a class also having a constructor which initializes something else, this will fail.

Answer (score 2):

You could use the interface injection pattern: implement an interface `iPrimaryModelRest` into the same class that uses the trait `PrimaryModelRest`:

```
interface iPrimaryModelRest {
  public function init();
  public abstract function getPrimaryModelClass();
}
```

The class that uses the trait woud look like this:

```
class cMyClass implements iPrimaryModelRest {
  use PrimaryModelRest;
}
```

Then, whenever the class is instantiated (not only autoloaded) you could call a special factory-like initialisation function like this:

```
class cMyApp {
  public function start() {
    /** @var cMyClass $oClass */  // enlighten IDE
    $oClass = $this->init(new cMyClass);
  }
  public function init($oClass) {
    if ($oClass instanceof iPrimaryModelRest) {$oClass->init();}
    if ($oClass instanceof whateverinterface) {
      // pass optional stuff, like database connection
    }
  }
}
```

The interface is used to determine the capabilities of the class, and sets data/runs corresponding functions. If I'm not mistaken then this pattern is called a [Service Locator](https://martinfowler.com/articles/injection.html).

Answer (score 1):

I needed a trait for database connection. To avoid using the __construct in a trait, I've used a magic getter instead:

```php
trait WithDatabaseConnection
{
    public function __get(string $name)
    {
        if ($name === 'pdo') {
            return App::make(\PDO::class);
        }

        trigger_error("Property $name does not exist.");

        return null;
    }
}
```

```php
class Foo {
  use WithDatabaseConnection;

  public function save() {
    $this->pdo->query('...');
  }
}
```